# iOS silent remote push notification not working: no user visible content

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send silent remote push notifications from a PHP server to an iOS device. Set up using the information at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

When I send the message I can see it being received by the iOS device (iOS version 12.4.7).
But I also can see an error "Notification has no user visible content".
Now this being a silent background notification, and having the header `apns-push-type:background` set, I would think there is not need for user visible content?

```
[xxxxx] Not delivering user visible push notification B026-EC8D [ error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1401 "Notification has no user visible content" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notification has no user visible content} ]
```

The notifications work when the application is in background mode but not when the app is closed.

I have tried sending a normal non-background alert, and that works fine, even if the app is closed.

Below is a simple class/function I created for testing

```
class SimpleApnsService
{
    public static function push($deviceToken, $certificate, $topic)
    {
        $payload = '{
            "appdata": "command:refresh",
            "aps": {
                "content-available": 1
            }
        }';

        $url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$deviceToken";

        $headers = [
            "apns-topic:$topic",
            "apns-push-type:background",
            "apns-priority:5",
        ];

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // there is not password set on the certificate
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certificate);

        // return true
        $response = curl_exec($ch); => return true

        // returns 200
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    }
}
```